# заполнить двумерный массив случайными числами, посчитать сумму элементов главной и побочной диагонали

Tags: c, массивы

я написала такой код, но все числа в столбцах одинаковые. Почему так получается и как сделать их разными? спасибо!

```
 #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()

{ int n,i=0, j=0;
int primary[i], secondary[i];
int primsum=0, secsum=0;
srand(time(0));

printf("enter the number of rows and columns\n");
    scanf(" %d", &n);


    int matrix[i][j];

     for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        for(j=0; j<n; j++){
            matrix[i][j]= rand() %100;}}


      for(i=0; i<n; i++)
        {for(j=0; j<n; j++){
           printf(" %-5d", matrix[i][j]);}
                printf("\n");
        }

for (i=0; i<n; i++){
    primary[i]= matrix[i][i];
secondary[i]= matrix[n-(i+1)][i];}

for (i=0; i<n; i++){
    primsum+=primary[i];
    secsum+= secondary[i];}

    printf("the sum of primary diagonal is %d\n", primsum);
    printf("the sum of secondary diagonal is %d\n", secsum);



    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Память под матрицу неверно выделятеся, отсюда и глюки

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    int n;
    int primsum=0, secsum=0;
    srand(time(0));

    printf("enter the number of rows and columns: ");
    scanf(" %d", &n);

    int ** matrix = malloc(sizeof(int*)*n);
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        matrix[i] = malloc(sizeof(int)*n);

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            matrix[i][j]= rand() %100;

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            printf(" %-5d", matrix[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        primsum += matrix[i][i];
        secsum  += matrix[n-(i+1)][i];}

    printf("the sum of primary diagonal is %d\n", primsum);
    printf("the sum of secondary diagonal is %d\n", secsum);

    return 0;
}
```

Освобождение выделенной для `matrix` памяти напишите самостоятельно.

Comment: Блин, студентота так  ничему не научится. Впрочем, это их проблемы.

Comment: @gbg Ну всегда же хочется верить в хорошее :) - что сядет, посмотрит, разберется, как сделано, почему...

Comment: я не студентка, я для себя учу, интересно просто, так что непременно разберусь. Спасибо большое

Comment: @Harry, а зачем Вы использовали указатель на указатель? Просто указателя недостаточно? Объясните пожалуйста

Comment: Просто указатель можно использовать, выделить память под N^2 элементов - то тогда будет нельзя обращаться как `matrix[i][j]`, надо будет писать `matrix[i*N+j]`...